# Swift: AVPlayer playing sound but no video

Tags: xcode8

Does anyone know the solution to this? I can hear video but can't see it in the simulator.

```
    func playinitiate() {

        let locationVideo = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video", ofType: "mov")!)

        let video = AVPlayer(url: locationVideo as URL)

        let videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: video)

        videoLayer.frame = specialView.bounds

        specialView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

        videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        video.play()

        print("Player is running")
```

Comment: why dont u check in device ?

Comment: Is there a specific code to check in device? In my code I call playinitiate() if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: yes may be, if you have demo prject then attach so that i can check and fix your issie

Comment: Here is a link for my swift login Controller, I am trying to put the video in the container I called superview: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NoUzQCM1ePcnhjUy11V1A4N28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: let me check it first

Comment: I appreciate your help!